# Why does the derivative of an InterpolatingFunction fluctuate so much?

Tags: interpolation, smoothing

```
data1 =
 Uncompress@
  FromCharacterCode@
   Flatten@
    ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1sze.png"], "Byte"];

α = Interpolation[data1, Method -> "Spline"];
Plot[{α[x], α'[x]}, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image: plot of function and highly fluctuating first derivative]

The original function is smooth, so I don't understand why the derivative fluctuates so much. How should we eliminate this fluctuation?

Comment: Take a look at ``Show[ListPlot[data1[[12500 ;;, All]]], Plot[\[Alpha][x], {x, 0, .03}, PlotStyle -> Red]]`` and you will see that your datapoints (and therefore also the interpolation) are very wiggly. You are probably not looking for *interpolation*, but some kind of *smoothing*.

Comment: There are several ways to do this, depending on what the actual final goal is. Since you have equidistant points, you can for example use ``LowpassFilter``. ``dataSmooth = Transpose[{data1[[All, 1]], LowpassFilter[data1[[All, 2]], 0.01]}]; α = Interpolation[dataSmooth, Method -> "Spline"]; Show[ListPlot[data1, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> {-.1, 1.1}], Plot[{α[x], α'[x]}, {x, 0, 2}]]``

Comment: @Domen I see it. Thanks very much.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it's probably better to filter the data or do fitting instead of forcing an interpolation through all the data points. For instance, cubic B-spline fitting:

```
With[{n = 50},
  Fit[data1,
   Table[
    BSplineBasis[
     {3, Join[ConstantArray[Min[data1[[All, 1]]], 3],
       Subdivide[Sequence @@ MinMax[data1[[All, 1]]], n - 2],
       ConstantArray[Max[data1[[All, 1]]], 3]]},
     i, x], {i, 0, n}], x]] //
 Plot[{#, D[#, x]},
   {x, Sequence @@ MinMax[data1[[All, 1]]]}, Evaluated -> True] &
```

[image]